# Make user Control visible using Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

All I want to make user control visible on button click. I am getting object null typical error on following code.   How do I make complete user Control visible or invisible using javascript?

```
Dim ucAddNewChekcing As SubscriberSetupPages_UserControls_CheckingAccount
            ucAddNewChekcing = DirectCast(pnlTopLevel.Items().FindItemByValue("pnlAddChecking").FindControl("CheckingAcct1"), SubscriberSetupPages_UserControls_CheckingAccount)
            Dim openWinScript As String = "SetVisibility('" & ucAddNewChekcing.ClientID & "');"
            btnAddChecking.OnClientClick = openWinScript
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please start to accept more answers. This helps the community and gives satisfaction to the user who helped you.

Comment: If your `ucAddNewChekcing` has its `Visible` property set to false in the codebehind, it will be impossible to make it visible in Javascript because it won't exist on the page. How are you setting it not to display in the first place?

Comment: If my problems are solved, I will accept the answer right-a-way.

Comment: Out of 12 questions you've asked, only one of them has been solved?

Comment: Yes By default this is the code to set it invisible. 
  <UC1:CheckingAcct ID="CheckingAcct1" Name="CheckingAcct1" runat="server" visible="false" AcctID="0"  />  
On button click user wants to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

have visible="false" set means your control doesn't get rendered at all, so there's no element available when you want to display it. you can address this in a couple ways:

leave the control visible, so it renders, and use css styling to hide it until you want it: <del>`style="display: none;"` in place of `visible="false"`.</del>

change `visible` to `true` and set `style="display: none;"` on some wrapping element (see edit below).

in your `SetVisibility` function, you can do

```
    element.style.display = '';
```

to remove the `none` value and show the element.

edit: ok after thinking about this some more, we can't put `style="display: none;"` right in the user control tag because that doesn't map to any specific html element. instead, this needs to be set on an element that wraps the contents of the user control. 

if the user control has such an element already, that would be a good place to set the display styling. you can add a method to the control that will return the ClientID for that element so you can reference it in script.
otherwise if your layout will tolerate it you can put the control inside an `asp:Panel` and set the display property there.

the other option is to wrap your control in an UpdatePanel containing some control (like `HiddenField`) as a flag which will indicate if the control is visible or not. if you go that route you `SetVisibility` function looks something like

```
    // change value on flag control
    hiddenControl.value = '1';

    // trigger a partial postback
    __doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');
```

and then in your `UpdatePanel_Load` function you can check the value of your flag control and set the `Visible` property on your user control accordingly.

Comment: I have treid solution one but display none is not making user control invisible. I have useed following script.

  <UC1:CheckingAcct ID="CheckingAcct1" runat="server" style="display:none;"  AcctID="0" />

Comment: @user228777 made some changes.